# In WPF Project I have separate folder for each module I want default app.xaml file to be loaded whenever I hit that module screen

Tags: wpf, xaml, silverlight, migration

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XEB5.png)I am migrating my project from Silverlight to WPF and In Silverlight each module has different project and it's own configuration file i.e. App.xaml. But while migrating it in my WPF project I have separate folder for each modules. In WPF we are adding silverlight library files into WPF folder. So how we can initialize app.xaml file in WPF at folder level?

Comment: In wpf there will be one application entry point and only one app xaml used for that. These are merged resources you're intending to switch out? Merge in resource dictionaries specific to your modules and arrange things so they replace base resources. Whichever is merged last with the same x:Key will win. Bind to them using dynamicresource.

Comment: @Andy Do you mean add xaml as <ResourceDictionary Source="module1/module1.xaml" /> in common app.xaml file? by changing app.xaml to module1.xaml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to " So how we can initialize app.xaml file in WPF at folder level?" is:

You cannot do that.

You might be able to do something similar will satisfy your requirements. Assuming you're talking resources.

Consider a single resource in a resource dictionary with an x:Key of "XX".

When you merge that in app.xaml it's added to a hashtable with a key of XX and value of whatever your resource is.  That goes into Application.Current.Resources.

If your wpf app then loads any usercontrol, window whatever that uses a dynamicresource XX then it gets that value.  Doesn't matter where it is loaded from. That could be a different library or whatever you like.

Resources have scope.

You could therefore merge a resource dictionary at window level. Say you added another resource dictionary in a module.  You merge it into Window1's resources and it has something with a x:Key of "XX".  Anything in that instance of Window1's visual tree will grab that "new" XX you just merged in.  Anything in any other window will still be using that one out of Application.Current.Resources.

You could conceivably merge resource dictionaries at usercontrol level in this way.  This is usually a bad idea though because each gets an instance in memory of your resources. That can add up to a lot of memory if you're not careful.

You could therefore arrange things so each module has it's own window ( or some other parent ) which merges in it's own somehow unique resource dictionary. That supplies a more local version of any resources you need.

Or

Maybe the user only navigate to and hence sees one module at a time. Whatever a module is.

You could then merge your resource dictionaries in at application level. Everything gets them then though.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Finally Creating the Project for Each module worked for me.

Comment: I have the two WPF applications "Application A" and Application B. From "Application A" I am navigating to "ABC.xaml" page of "Application B". I want to call app.xaml.cs file of "Application B" before navigate to "ABC.xaml" page. Is this possible?

Comment: @andy - What if the other WPF projects (modules) are structured same way like Silverlight as separate WPF projects in solution, with each module holding its own App.xaml.
I see navigation is possible from one WPF project in a solution to another WPF project but it doesn't call App.xaml of that project like the way Silverlight does. Any reason why this will not work, since both are from same family?
Any workaround then? since it is not possible to move all code from App.xaml of modules to root WPF project as it will bring conflicts.

Comment: Only the entry point app.xaml will be used. Any dll referenced are loaded in the context of the entry point's app.  I outlined work rounds.